# How to make a play/resume button in Objective C with sprite kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, sprite-kit

so I have successfully made a working Pause button in Objective-C with Sprite Kit, but I am not sure how I can make the scene resume with a play button and change the pause button to a resume button.  I also made a boolean called isPaused because I thought that may be useful.  Here is my code for my pause button when touched:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"pauseButton"]) {
    self.scene.view.paused = YES;
    self.isPaused = YES;

}

if (!self.isStarted){
    [self start];
}
else if (self.isGameOver){
    [self clear];
}
else{
    [hero jump];
}

}
```

And here is my code for the pause button in the same file(MyScene)

```
- (SKSpriteNode *)pauseButtonNode
{
SKSpriteNode *pauseButton = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"pauseButton.png"];
pauseButton.position = CGPointMake(250,140);
pauseButton.name = @"pauseButton";//how the node is identified later
pauseButton.zPosition = 1.0;
return pauseButton;
}
```

Comment: if you pause the view none of the nodes will receive any input event, you got to pause just the node that contains the to-be-paused nodes while the pause menu and buttons must be on an extra layer (a node)

Comment: Okay how do I do that?

Comment: like i said, you have at least two nodes in the scene, one has all the nodes you want to pause and the other has all the nodes you want to be interactive/animated while the other is paused

Comment: @LearnCocos2D pausing the view does not stop input events.